# Is there any Eclipse plugin which autobackup a project every so and so minutes to an email a/c?

Tags: eclipse, email, backup

Is there any Eclipse plugin which autobackup a project every so and so minutes to an email a/c?

Comment: Might be time to learn Eclipse plugins :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that such a feature is already present in Eclipse. Eclipse stores every new edit in a file in the following backup folder present in the workspace folder `.metadata`:

```
 {Eclipse root directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/
```

The backup can also be accessed from right clicking a file and choosing "Restore from Local History...". However, when it comes to emailing the code, there is no such function that comes with default version of Eclipse, so I guess I do need to learn Eclipse Plugin.

Here are some relevant links:

- http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2008/1/18/How-to-recover-a-deleted-file-in-Eclipse
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_is_the_workspace_local_history_stored%3F

Comment: Thanks! This just saved my day's work after mercurial messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Subversive/Subclipse

Answer (score 0):

Installing a CVS would do it, but any backup utility software running in the background would also work.